# Merging multiple stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString into one

Tags: ios, swift

I have to use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` for multiple cases, I was wondering if there is a better way of writing the code below into possibly a single line?

```
let newString = list.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
let newString2 = newString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("(", withString: "")
let newString3 = newString2.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "")
let newString4 = newString3.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
```

Comment: My first question would be: *"Why is that necessary?"* – Why do you need to remove parentheses, space and newline characters from the string? Perhaps the problem can better be solved at an earlier point, where the string is created?

Comment: @MartinR: It's usually an attempt on having-to-not-use RegEx.

Comment: @VatsalManot: That may be, I don't know, that's why I am asking. It may also be that the string was obtained by calling `description` on an NSArray or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Write an extension.**

```
extension String
{
    public mutating func replace(substrings: [String], with other: String)
    {
        substrings.forEach({ self = stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString($0, withString: other) })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way:

```
let clean = "(abc (def)\tghi )\n".stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(
  "[()[:space:]]",
  withString: "",
  options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably more efficient to let Foundation optimize the multiple search/replace operations with a character set. (You could also make a single search/replace operation with a regular expression, but if all you need to replace is single characters, a character set might result in better performance — generally, the more specifically you can state your problem to the API, the better a solution it can provide.)

```
let chars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "() \n")
text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(chars).joinWithSeparator("")
```

Oddly, Foundation can trim a charset from the start/end of a string, but not strip from within a string. It can split a string by charset, though, so then all you have to do is splice it back together with an empty separator. You could, of course, wrap that up in your own extension for convenience:

```
extension String {
    func stringByStrippingCharactersInSet(set: NSCharacterSet) -> String {
        return self.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(chars).joinWithSeparator("")
    }
    mutating func stripCharactersInSet(set: NSCharacterSet) {
        self = self.stringByStrippingCharactersInSet(set)
    }
}
```